# How to add border and body blur effect on LinearGradient?

Tags: css, react-native, expo

I need to make this linear gradient and blur effect on expo + react native.

[image]   ##Design< ___    >I tried##[image]

Here's the css style of this design.

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFFFFF -4.55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 80.21%);
opacity: 0.4;
filter: blur(16px);
```

I tried this with `LinearGradient` and `BlurView` like below.

> Here is the full code on [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@antoniocholony/bad-tortillas).

```
<BlurView
  tint="light"
  intensity={10}
  blurType="dark"
  blurAmount={200}
  blurRadius={300}
>
  <LinearGradient
    colors={['#ffffff88', '#00000000']}
    style={{ height: 400, width: 100, alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 5 }}>
    </LinearGradient>
</BlurView>
```

How to make that similar to design? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it by using two LinearGradients.

One is from top to bottom and another is from left to right.

Then you don't need to use `BlurView` at all.

Hope It will help you!

Comment: Could you provide some codes about your answer? Thanks.